# How to hide a C++ function definition before releasing source code

Tags: c++

I am building a Windows (Visual Studio, C++ based) console application and would like to release the source code for it. However, I do not want the definition of a particular function be visible to it. Is there a way to pre-compile (just the file containing the definition) it so that no one can view it, but the rest of the source is visible and can be built/ran using the 'pre-compiled' function definition?

Comment: Of course, just compile that particular source file into an object file or library.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth "release source" not "release binary"

Comment: @Aitch "way to pre-compile (just the file containing the definition) it so that no one can view it" is kind'a "release binary"

Comment: What do you mean saying "to hide" some functions if you want release source code?

Comment: I want users to be unable to mess with this one particular function, but otherwise, they are free to change the flow of the application in any way they like. This function implements the core functionality of the application

Comment: Okay true, just providing the source declaration (e.g. .h) and the binary definition (e.g. .a, .lib). I didn't write such secret codelines I had to hide.

Comment: @AbhijatBiswas : there is no way in hell to guarantee that your "users are unable to mess with this one particular function". Please do realise that before making any decisions.

Comment: @Aitch, thanks I might try that.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: I don't think compiling  it into a .lib would let them reverse engineer it?

Comment: @AbhijatBiswas : machine code is perfectly reverse-engineerable. It takes time, but it is.

Comment: ... then there's no way to really hide a function!

Comment: If that function is really that interesting, reverse-engineering binaries is actually not very hard.

Comment: @DonReba Really? How complex are we talking in man hours?

Comment: @AbhijatBiswas, you can see functions, loops, arrays, and operations. Disassemblers, like Olly, help by indicating jump targets. For mathematical algorithms, not having variable names is often not even a big handicap, but complicated business logic can be a pain to figure out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two basic choices:

- have that function in a compiled form

  - if you only want to ship source code, you could compile a shared library, then find or write a utility to generate C/C++ source code with a character array containing the binary file content, then your program can `ifstream::write()` to a file and link (e.g. `dlopen()`) the shared library on the fly at runtime (this doesn't buy you much over just shipping the shared library unless you have pressing reasons for needing a "source-only" release, and the above qualifies for your purposes)
- obfuscate the source code in some way that removes the value or insight potentially gained by reading it

  - there are number of source code obfuscation utilities around (specific recommendations are off-topic for S.O.)
  - one form of obfuscation is to generate an assembly language version (e.g. `g++ -S`, `cl /S`) of the C++ sources, which would be verbose and harder for most programmers to understand and modify further

Comment: Thanks, this was basically what I wanted to confirm. I don't think obfuscation is going to cut it. Maybe compiling is the way to go.

Comment: @AbhijatBiswas Fair enough.  Do remember to `strip` the binary of symbol/debug information too.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. When you release the source code, then the information about the function is there. If you release it in some way 'pre-compiled' and the function is still called then the information is still there. If you require the function to stay a secret you must not release it.